# Finding keys in string enclosed with [[ ]]

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string which has some keys between [[]].

```
 string s = "<p>Hi [[USER]],<br/>How are you doing<br/>Regards,<br/>[[SENDER]]</p>";
```

I want to first fetch the key names USER and SENDER in a list which i am tyring to do by:

```
 var keys = new List<string>();
        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(s, @"[[(.*?)]]")) 
        {
            keys.Add(match.Value);
        }
```

However, The keys are coming empty.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Also, I tried using << >> instead of [[ ]] which is working but words disappear  when I load data into << >>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need to escape '[':

```
string s = "<p>Hi [[USER]],<br/>How are you doing<br/>Regards,<br/>[[SENDER]]</p>";

var keys = new List<string>();
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(s, @"\[\[(.*?)]]"))
{
    keys.Add(match.Value.Trim('[').Trim(']'));
}
```

To exclude the `[[]]` without trimming, use `@"(?<=\[\[)(.*?)(?=])"`

Or as @wiktor-stribiżew pointed out, you can simplify that to be:

```
var keys = Regex.Matches(s, @"\[\[(.*?)]]").Cast<Match>()
                                          .Select(p => p.Groups[1].Value).ToList()
```

Comment: You don't need to escape closing brackets, they aren't special characters.

Comment: Just `var keys = Regex.Matches(s, @"\[\[(.*?)]]").Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Groups[1].Value).ToList()` can turn out enough.

Answer (score 0):

[ and ] are regex (I forgot the word... tokens?) tokens. Try escaping them: `\[\[.*\]\]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var keys = (from Match m in Regex.Matches(s, @"\[\[(.*?)]]") select m.Groups[1] + "").ToList();
```