# Regex to match exact words in double square brackets

Tags: c#, regex

I have a following regex, which matches words inside double bracket squares:

```
@"(?<=\[\[)[^]]+(?=\])"
```

Problem:
I want to replace in input

```
[[Hello]] -> Foo
[[HelloWorld]] -> Bar
```

Code is following:

```
message = message.Replace(match.Value, value.ToString());
message = Regex.Replace(message, @"[\[\]']+", "");
```

In output, I receive FooWorld. How should I modify my regex to get Foo and Bar?

Comment: Just `message = message.Replace("[[", "").Replace("]]", "")` should be enough.

Comment: Please confirm you need no replacing, but just to collect all the strings inside `[[` and `]]`. As for me, *Problem: I want to replace in input* makes this question different from [*Finding keys in string enclosed with `[[ ]]`*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38030692/finding-keys-in-string-enclosed-with).

Comment: Since the above mentioned answer provides an *extraction* solution, and this one requires a *replacing* one, the question should be reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex `@"(?<=\[\[)[^]]+(?=\])"` matches 1+ characters other than `]` if preceded with `[[` and followed with `]`. It does not really match `[[x  x x]]`-like strings. It would not even match `[[x y ] bracket ]]`-like strings.

You could achieve what you need with [`@"\[\[(.*?)]]"`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5b%5c%5b(.*%3f)%5d%5d&i=%5b%5bHello%5d%5d%0d%0a%5b%5bHelloWorld%5d%5d&r=%241) regex (using the `RegexOptions.Singleline` flag), and replacing with `$1`:

```
message = Regex.Replace("[[Hello]]", @"\[\[(.*?)]]", "$1"));
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/Ys4lph)

However, given your current requirements (or their absence) you can just use

```
 message = message.Replace("[[", "").Replace("]]", "");
```